# Is it legal to use school logo in my free mobile app?

Tags: copyright

I am developing a smartphone app to serve as a bulletin board for some schools.

I plan to use school logos to represent those schools in my app.

Might this cause trouble through copyright breach or other legal problems?

Comment: If you've asked the schools and they said yes, there's no problem. If you asked the schools and they said no, that's not going to change regardless of what we tell you. If you haven't asked the schools at all, why the heck not?

Comment: I didn't ask because there are too many schools and I am the only person working on this. Let me ask a few schools.